# Bootstrap to PDF Conversion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wkhtmltopdf

I am using Bootstrap 2.3 in a legacy tool to render a page that covers a project with at a glance details. I am trying to then render that single page as a PDF that can be downloaded.

I tried several tools including things like DOM 2 PDF but they require very basic html elements.

I found `wkhtmltopdf` and at the very basic level it seems to render the DOM correctly but I am running into some column issues.

The page it self has a 3 column structure, 3-6-3. When I render the pdf however, it turns all of the columns into 12 stacked on top of each other.

This is how the page looks in my UI:
[image]

This is what my PDF looks like after exporting:
[image]

So from what I can tell, its not using the `print` css because it would be a lot more basic than what it is. However I don't know why its spanning 12 cols and not the way I have it set up.

Is there some css I can add to the columns in order to have it render correctly?

**UPDATE**

I was actually able to pass a custom view port size using the plugin which then rendered the page correctly.

Comment: First of all you should go with col-xs. That seems the best column width. I have dealt with the same issues and wrote my own css. I have set up three files, one general print css, one of a4 and one for a3. To get an idea of what's going on see my repo: https://github.com/hmt/sahib/tree/master/views However, this repo is meant to display documents created in html and css. But the conversion is to PDF via wkhtmltopdf as well.

Comment: are you using Bootstrap 3 though @three? I don't think col-xs is supported in 2.3

Comment: sorry, BS3. I was so eager pushing that knowledge I missed that important snippet.

Comment: Could you explain your update? I am just curious because I am running into the exact same problem, and are you still using the wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: @mjwrazor - I ended up using a plugin called WKPDF which allowed me to pas a view port size (resolution) which then rendered bootstrap in its normal col sizes `wkhtmltopdf --viewport-size 1280x1024 --orientation Landscape http://site_name.com file_name.pdf`

Comment: oh :/. I am looking for something I can use inside of a website. ng-click() and then download the current page in its current state as pdf. Trying to make a button to do that from the angular side and not Node on the MEAN stack. None developers would use so people who don't know how to access the cmd line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `col-xs-*` because PDF contains A4 size.

Comment: Can you please add more details and explain the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's rendering at a lower viewport width.  You could change your columns from `col-md-6` to `col-sm-6` for example, to change the breakpoint.

Comment: I assume that would work for BS3 but I am forced to use 2.3 for this tool which rely on spans I believe?